# Is there a way to hide the x and y axis when using the ScatterPlotItem and PlotCurveItem

Tags: python, pyqtgraph

I'm plotting a 2-D numpy array using pyqtgraph. I wanted to plot my data without an x or y axis. At the moment my plot looks like this

[image]

but I don't want an x or y axis. I was hoping for something like this

[image]

The way I'm plotting is by creating a PlotWidget object and adding it to my main window. After the user loads that data I create a ScatterPlotItem and PlotCurveItem and add it to the PlotWidget.

I tried reading the documentation for PlotWidget, ScatterPlotItem, and PlotCurveItem and I wasn't really able to find a way of hiding the axes.

I was wondering whether there is a way of just plotting the points and the lines without the x,y axis?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

see [PlotItem.hideAxis()](https://pyqtgraph.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api_reference/graphicsItems/plotitem.html#pyqtgraph.PlotItem.hideAxis)

```
import pyqtgraph as pg
import numpy as np

app = pg.mkQApp()

x = np.random.rand(10,)
y = np.random.rand(10,)

w = pg.PlotWidget()
c = pg.PlotCurveItem(x,y)
s = pg.ScatterPlotItem(x,y)

w.addItem(c)
w.addItem(s)

w.getPlotItem().hideAxis('bottom')
w.getPlotItem().hideAxis('left')

w.show()

app.exec()
```

Result:

[image: no axis]